# How to update the alarm ringing time  While updating calendar events?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set alarm for calendar events that are inserted through my application. I have also set alarm for events(i.e) when calendar event notification shows, Alarm also sounded. Now, if I update the event time, I must get the alarm time also be updated from old time to new time. How to make out this? 
Any help is highly appreciated and Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does android have any 'foreign key' type relationship between Events and their Reminders in its calendar content provider? I think there it is, and can help you. The link below is from android calendar app's source, and it is related to edit event activity, used in editing and inserting events. in `save()` method, used in this class, you can find how android itself saves events, and stores them, I think it would help.
[click to see android calendar src code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.1_r2/com/android/calendar/EditEvent.java)

Comment: Hi, I've gone through the link above. I have separately set Alarm notification including with Calendar notification. Now when the calendar event time is updated, i cannot update the alarm time. So this causing the problem.